# Get ID where Group by PartnerID, Max(ChangeDate) - fast

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

i got the following Table:

```
Sampletable
{
 ID int, 
 PartnerID int, 
 ChangeDate datetime
}
```

i want all `IDs` grouped by `PartnerID` with the highest `Changedate`.

Is there a performant way or would you recommend something else to do to get a similar structure?

PS: im Using microsoft sql server 2012

Edit: 
I already got a way that works but i think there may be a more performant solution:

```
Select pas.Id, pas1.ChangeDate
from Sampletable pas
inner join (SELECT PartnerID, Max(ChangeDate) as ChangeDate FRom Sampletable Group by PartnerID) pas1 on pas1.PartnerID = pas.PartnerId AND pas1.ChangeDate = pas.ChangeDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can try like this...

```
Select ID , 
PartnerID , 
ChangeDate 
from 
( Select  Row_Number() Over (Partition by PartnerID  order by ChangeDate  Desc) as Row, Id
  PartnerID , 
  ChangeDate 
  from SampleTable
) t where row=1
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a good approach! But cant really tell yet which one is faster, sometimes my one sometimes your one

Comment: @Marguth i m also not sure too....about perfroemnace i answer it before your edit...so my answer get desired result...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT pas.Id,
       pas.ChangeDate
FROM Sampletable pas
WHERE pas.ChangeDate = (SELECT Max(pas1.ChangeDate) 
                        FROM Sampletable pas1 
                        WHERE pas1.PartnerID = pas.PartnerId)
```